# Nativescript + Angular 2 base screen template

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to create some base screen template (master screen) and use it in other screens?
For example I have application Component like this

```
@Component({
selector: "main",
directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Bar], 
template : `
  <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <bar-component>
    </bar-component>
    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
` })
```

I'd like to have  in all screens, but now I have it only on my very first screen ("" route) and then after changing screen using `this._router.navigate(["/details"]);` ("details" route) I can't see my . Do I do something wrong? Could you tell my please how can I create this functionality if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

try use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` instead of `<page-router-outlet>`.

I think this test code from nativescript angular, shows what you want to do:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/ng-sample/app/examples/router/router-outlet-test.ts